# MySql procedure with select with update variable inside

Tags: mysql, variables, select, set, procedure

```
declare prioritaC INT default 1;
select
  case
    when (b.zraneni = 0 and a.center_id is not null) then (
      a.center_id
    ) else (
      select hokejista_id
        from nahradnik
       where nahradnikTyp_id = 3 and tym_id = 1 and priorita = prioritaC
      set prioritaC = prioritaC + 1;
    )
    end as center_id_real
  from oslabeni45 a
  left join hokejista b on (a.center_id = b.id)
```

Why is impossible to `set prioritaC = prioritaC + 1` in case when statement? How can be variable increment in select?

Comment: You need to increment your row value in an update statement!

Comment: How can be declared variable incremented in an update statement?

Answer (score 0):

The point that the other commenters are making in short-hand is that there are *TWO* separate CASE cobstructs in MySQL.  One is a case statement that you use in procedural code and the other is a functional construct that you use inside a SELECT statement or clause.

In this example you have a SELECT statement containing a CASE construct.  The result compronent must be expressions.  You can't put statements here.

You need to move any statements outside the SELECT.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But I need a variable in select with case, is there any possibility how to fix it?

Comment: In a procedure, you SELECT ... **INTO** ...  You can then follow this by IF THEN ELSE END IF logic or CASE  ... END CASE statements and include any assignments here.  If you want this variable to persist across procedure calls, then it must be stored in a table.

Comment: I need variable prioritaC only in select statement and I need increment it only if row in statement is (b.zraneni > 0 or a.center_id is null). I need this variable to select statement as you can see in code.

Comment: SELECT statements are SELECT statements.  You can select results from a database using them.  You _cannot_ increment variables in a select statement, unless you care to rewrite the MySQL engine.  Do a SELECT; do your logic, and if necessary do a separate update inside this logic.

Comment: Ok so I have to rewrite it, but I don´t know how to make this sample code functional...

Comment: Do the select as a (oslabeni45 left join hokejista) left join nahradnik to get the center_id, priorita_id and then do the selection in logic based on which is null. I can't give you a full solution because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is not possible. I need select center_id from oslabeni45 (in english oslabeni is power play line in hockey). If center_id is null or is injured (zraneni) then I need replace center_id with a value from nahradnik (sub player). Priorita (priority) is a priority - in the first occasion is set to 1, in the second occasion I want to set it to 2. I don´t know how many times I must replace players in this select - it may be 0..n times, so I need a variable to check which sub player will be here in a particular row (value priorita in where part of select).